# F# Xml TypeProvider for C#

Tags: c#, .net, f#, type-providers, f#-data

Is there an equivalent to the [F# TypeProvider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html) in C#? I am looking at the easiest way to read an Xml file with C#. At this point I am planning to use XDocument, but I was wondering if there was something better.

F# makes it so easy to read an Xml file that I wonder if I shouldn't switch language for Xml processing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, C# does not support type providers and there is no easy way for emulating them (as Gustavo mentioned, you could use *generated type providers* through a small F# library, but XML, JSON, CSV and others are not this kind.)

I think using F# library that does the processing is the best approach.

A more complicated alternative would be to write code that lets you define types to model the XML file in C# and then automatically reads the file into these classes. I do not think anything like this exists, but I wrote a similar thing in F# (before type providers), so you can see [the snippet for inspiration](http://fssnip.net/jk). The usage looks like this:

```
// Modelling RSS feeds - the following types define the structure of the
// expected XML file. The StructuralXml parser can automatically read
// XML file into a structure formed by these types.
type Title = Title of string
type Link = Link of string
type Description = Description of string

type Item = Item of Title * Link * Description
type Channel = Channel of Title * Link * Description * list<Item>
type Rss = Rss of Channel

// Load data and specify that names in XML are all lowercase
let url = "http://feeds.guardian.co.uk/theguardian/world/rss"
let doc : StructuralXml<Rss> = 
  StructuralXml.Load(url, LowerCase = true)

// Match the data against a type modeling the RSS feed structure
let (Rss(channel)) = doc.Root
let (Channel(_, _, _, items)) = channel
for (Item(Title t, _, _)) in items do
  printfn "%s" t
```

Answer (score 4):

Is there any reason why you can't add an F# library to your solution?  That project can create the abstraction over the XML that you want, and you could consume it from your C# projects.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible to use type providers directly in C#.

For generated type providers, you can "instantiate" the type provider in a F# project, and then use that from C#, but that doesn't work for erased type providers like `CsvProvider`, `JsonProvider`, `XmlProvider`, `Freebase` or `Worldbank`. (*It will work for the builtin SqlProvider and WsdlProvider, though*).

There has been some discussion of switching `CsvProvider`, `JsonProvider` and `XmlProvider` to the generated model so they're usable for data-binding in C# (https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/134#issuecomment-20104995), but that will probably take a while to happen.

My suggestion is to either swtich to F# altogether, or create record types that mirror the types that the type provider creates. Example:

```
type T = {
    A : int
    B : string
    (...)
}

type XmlT = XmlProvider<"xml file">

let getXml() =
    let xml = XmlT.GetSample()
    { A = xml.A
      B = xml.B
      (...) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your link to the XmlProvider in F# and I have not seen anything like it in C#.  I use C# with Xml quite alot and often use XDocument and XElement to load and parse Xml with.  Once I have Xml loaded into the XDocument I use Linq to Xml to perform similar things.  I often use Linq Pad for general queries into the Xml which works well with C# not sure about F# though.